# Почему выдаётся ошибка 404, когда должна выдаваться 400?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Есть такой код:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetID(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id <= 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var User = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

        if (User == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(User);
    }
```

По условию если `id` не поступает и остается пустым, должна быть 400 ошибка, а на деле выдает 404, как мне это исправить? Я пробовал вместо `int` использовать `string`, но это не помогло.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в id ничего не поступает?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что URL с пустым id выглядит так:
https://localhost:44311/Api/User/ или https://localhost:44311/Api/User
то уверен.
Так как я новичок и это мой первый проект в web-api и вообще связанный в back-end, я могу что то путать и на самом деле это не пустое значение.

Comment: Вы возьмите дебаггер и проверьте, лежит ли в id что-нибудь

Comment: Я ставил точку остановки, когда пишу localhost:44311/Api/User/ точка остановки просто НЕ срабатывает, то есть не поступает ровном счет ничего.
А когда уже пишу  localhost:44311/Api/User/2 точка остановки срабатывает и id становиться равным 2.
Я не знаю, может я что то делаю не так, но облазив интернет я другого решения просто не нашел, как проверить на пустое значение id.

Comment: Стоп, если `id` - часть адреса, то ошибку 404 генерирует не ваш код, а сам сервер, ведь вы пытаетесь зайти по несуществующему адресу. В таком случае id лучше передавать через параметры.

Comment: Эх, весь день убил на эту проблему, а решение оказалось таким простым. 
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Получается, что нельзя передать пустое значение через адрес никаким способом ?

Comment: Если это числовое значение, то можно передавать 0 или none например. Можно ещё повесить обработчик на адрес без значения, и в нём выкидывать ошибку. Однако обычно в таких случаях предпочтительнее использовать параметры, ведь для этого они и нужны.

Answer (score 0):

int - это value type.
Он не может принимать значение null
нужно его привести к ссылочному

Comment: Вы не правы, тк `id` имеет ссылочный тип `int?`, который допускает значение null

Comment: @T0xee.n17 int - это примитивный тип, и он **не** может иметь значение `null`, в ответе это сказано верно.

Comment: @user20769056 пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. На данный момент ваш ответ не совсем понятен.

Comment: @Зонтик, не спорю, формально высказывание верное, однако оно не имеет отношения к ответу, т.к. там тип `int?`

Comment: А, ой. Я невнимательно смотрел код. Прошу прощения

Answer (score 0):

посмотрел на код... и на вскидку .. попробуйте проверять id перед его использованием в методе FindAsync.

Например, так:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetID(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue || id <= 0)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var User = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id.Value);

    if (User == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(User);
}
```

по идее теперь, если id пустой или не указан, будет выдаваться код ошибки 400 Bad Request.

надеюсь не много помог)